# How to Fix Dialog Fragment Error That Causes App To Crash

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

An error on my app's dialog fragment causes my app to crash. I recently used Roman Nurik's wizard pager and now, am experiencing these. Was there something wrong with how I used the codes? I am new to android and am finding a hard time what the message below meant.

> Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by
> the system, and anonymous classes are not static less... (⌘F1)
>
> Inspection info: From the Fragment documentation: Every fragment must
> have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring
> its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do
> not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors
> will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead,
> arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and
> later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().
>
> Issue id:
> ValidFragment

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mCurrentPageSequence.size()) {
                DialogFragment dg = new DialogFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                .setMessage(R.string.submit_confirm_message)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit_confirm_button, null)
                                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                                .create();
                    }
                };
                dg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "place_order_dialog");
            } else {
                if (mEditingAfterReview) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                } else {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I need to understand what I did wrong and how I can fix this moving forward.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Stacktrace or it didn't happen!

Comment: You're creating an anonymous `DialogFragment` subclass. You can't do that with `Fragment`s, for the reasons explained in the linked duplicates. Create a regular subclass of `DialogFragment` where you override `onCreateDialog()` – e.g., `public MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment` –  and use that instead.

Comment: @hardartcore -- my log cat has this message - "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{widevalue.com.widevalueautoinc/widevalue.com.widevalueautoinc.ActivityVehicle}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class com.example.android.wizardpager.wizard.ui.StepPagerStrip"

Comment: That's a different problem.